# Quarterly Reminder Emails

Tags: email

I am running SharePoint Foundation on a hosted site.  How do I send out a reminder email within five days of each quarter?

Thank you.

Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are running it as a hosted solution I guess you only can use Sandboxed solutions and that rules out Timer Jobs (which had been my first suggestion otherwise).

What you can do though is to use Workflows that pauses until a specified date.

Comment: Thanks Wictor for that piece of information.  I am glad that I can use workflows to do this.